# How to sort the keys in a dictionary alphabetically and put them in a list?

Tags: python

So far I have this code which is creating a dictionary from an input file:

```py
def read_file(filename):
    with open("menu1.csv") as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            line_strip = [line.rstrip('\n')]
            lines= [line.split(',')]
            result = {key: (float(fl), int(intg),
                      text.strip()) for key,
                      fl, intg,text in lines}
            print(result)
read_file("menu1.csv")
```

I have to keep that code in that def format. However, this outputs 27 different dictionaries. How do I make it so it is all in ONE dictionary?

ALso:
 I want to alphabetize the keys and put them into a list. I tried something like this but it won't work:

```
def alphabetical_menu(dict):

    names = []
    for name in d:
        names.append(name)
    names.sort()
    print(names)
```

What am I doing wrong? or do you have a way to do it?

Comment: Please fix code formatting

Comment: How exactly that "won't work" ?

Comment: `for name in d` - what is `d`? The function parameter is called `dict`.

Comment: The bottom section question I am just so confused. I was just trying random stuff. So in general, how would I alphabetize the keys and put them into a list?

Comment: can you post the content of the file or even the part of it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?

```
def read_file(filename):
    result = {}
    with open(filename) as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            line_strip = line.rstrip()
            line_split= line.split(',')
            key, fl, intg, text = tuple(line_split)
            result[key] = (float(fl), int(intg), text.strip())
    return result

def alphabetical_menu(d):
    return sorted(d.keys())

menu_dict = read_file("menu1.csv")
menu_sorted_keys = alphabetical_menu(menu_dict)

# To check the result
print(menu_dict)
print(menu_sorted_keys)
```

Comment: note: you should also return the result in `read_file` I think

Comment: Thank you! I think I need to get the first part working to then do this part.. Any ideas for making the first part into 1 dictionary?

Comment: @L_C I updated the code to get 1 dictionary on the first part. However since I don't really know how `menu1.csv` look like, so I can only guess :) Hope it helps!